# DRF React No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I set corsheaders but still getting the same error about corsheaders policy

Access to fetch at 'http://192.168.1.9:5000/posts/' from origin 'http://192.168.1.9:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

here's the settings.py code

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'channels',
    'djoser',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'chat.apps.ChatConfig',
    'user.apps.UserConfig',
    'general.apps.GeneralConfig'
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

and view.py code

```
class PostViewSet(ViewSet):

    def create(self, request):
        serial = PostSerializer(data=request.data, )
        if serial.is_valid():
            post = serial.save(author=request.user)
            if request.data.get('media') and int(request.data.get('media')) > 0:
                for x in range(int(request.data.get('media'))):
                    file = SnippetFile.objects.create(media=request.data.get('img_' + str(x)))
                    post.media.add(file)
            
            return Response({'post': PostSerializer(post).data})
        return Response(serial.errors)
```

and the urls.py

```
from rest_framework import routers

from blog.views import PostViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('posts', PostViewSet, basename='posts')

urlpatterns = [] + router.urls
```

and here's my frontend code

```
 fetch('http://192.168.1.9:5000/posts/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data`
            },
            body: formdata
        })
```

tried resetting browser cache but nothing seems to be working